# How can I extend node EventEmitter using revealing module pattern?

Tags: node.js, amd, eventemitter, node-modules

I've been trying to use node events.EventEmitter with my amdefine module (Revealing Module Pattern).  I've got a working piece of code where I implement an "on" function and pass this to an EventEmitter.

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') {
    var define = require('amdefine')(module);
}

define(function (require) {

    var events = require('events');
    var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

    function doSomething(strParam) {
        console.log('doSomething: ' + strParam);
        emitter.emit('done');
    }

    return {
        do: function(strParam) {
            doSomething(strParam);
        },
        on: function(event, callback) {
            emitter.addListener(event, callback);
        }
    }
});
```

This does the job. However, it seems like a better way would be to do inheritance instead -- so I can utilize all of the EventEmitter properties

```
[mycode].prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

But, I can't figure out how to do this with the RMP pattern above.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the need for this also.  Whilst searching for a solution I came across your question and subsequently came up with a solution that works just fine.

```
var events = require('events');

describe('test something', function() {

    var Person = function() {
        var evem = new events.EventEmitter();
        var funcs = {
            promote: promote
        };

        function promote() {
            evem.emit('promoted');
        }

        proxyFunctions(funcs, evem, ['on']);

        return Object.freeze(funcs);
    };

    function proxyFunctions(source, target, functions) {
        for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
            var functionName = functions[i];
            source[functionName] = function() {
                return target[functionName].apply(target, arguments);
            };
        }
    }

    it('can add event handlers', function(done) {
        var p = new Person();
        p.on('promoted', function() {
            done();
        });
        p.promote();

    });

});
```

https://gist.github.com/REAANDREW/10552871